# Angular 5 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am getting `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` error while I am trying to print all of my database records.

I have used this [source](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md) to get the data from firebase. Somehow it does not work. Is my json file structure wrong or the type of the array should be different?
What I am doing wrong?

**firebase (json)**

```
{
  "clients" : {
    "-L4jvQwBFM0W8A928waj" : {
      "id" : "124",
      "lastName" : "sda421",
      "name" : "412"
    },
    "-L4jz52GfcU4ZsJx_LX0" : {
      "id" : "214",
      "lastName" : "sda ",
      "name" : "sad "
    },
    "-L4k-5xNmN4dalqFj2dB" : {
      "id" : "12345678",
      "lastName" : "Pafasfbin",
      "name" : "fasf"
    },
    "-L4k-Dw5TA6FnHpWDiIq" : {
      "id" : "52353235",
      "lastName" : "qweqw",
      "name" : "qwrqwe "
    }
  }
}
```

**clients.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database' ;
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
  // clients: any[];
  clients: Observable<any[]>;

  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  id: number;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.clients = this.db.list('/clients').valueChanges();
    console.log(this.clients);
  }
}
```

**clients.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of clients">
    <label>name: </label> {{ i.name }}
    <label>lastName: </label> {{ i.lastName }}
    <label>ID: </label> {{ i.id }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to change `clients` to be a list, moving the hash to being a value in the object if necessary.

Comment: Why on earth do you not retrieve the data as list ? https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Comment: @Eliseo did everything almost the same as in the  source that you provided.

Comment: @bennn123, take acount that the link you post is "Retrieving data as objects", the link I post is "Retrieving data as lists"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Angular2+ ,
>
> you can't loop through the json object via ngFor , value should be
>   `Iterables such as Arrays` but in your case it's object , still if you
>   want to loop through object you can do something like this as per your
>   response

**Component Side:**

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

**Template Side :**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(clients)">
    <label>name: </label> {{ clients[key].name }}
    <label>lastName: </label> {{ clients[key].lastName }}
    <label>ID: </label> {{ clients[key].id }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-loop)**

Answer (score 0):

Check out following code snippet.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  clients:any;
  data=`{
  "clients" : {
    "-L4jvQwBFM0W8A928waj" : {
      "id" : "124",
      "lastName" : "sda421",
      "name" : "412"
    },
    "-L4jz52GfcU4ZsJx_LX0" : {
      "id" : "214",
      "lastName" : "sda ",
      "name" : "sad "
    },
    "-L4k-5xNmN4dalqFj2dB" : {
      "id" : "12345678",
      "lastName" : "Pafasfbin",
      "name" : "fasf"
    },
    "-L4k-Dw5TA6FnHpWDiIq" : {
      "id" : "52353235",
      "lastName" : "qweqw",
      "name" : "qwrqwe "
    }
  }
}`
objectKeys;
 ngOnInit(){
    this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
   this.clients=JSON.parse(this.data).clients;
   console.log(this.clients);
 }

}
```

---

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of objectKeys(clients)">

    <label>name: </label> {{ clients[i].name }}
    <label>lastName: </label> {{ clients[i].lastName }}
    <label>ID: </label> {{ clients[i].id }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nglqvb?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**